# How does dimension work?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, si-units

So, I know dimensions are the powers to which the base quantity is raised. For ex: we denote acceleration as LT^-1… But how does it work?
If i go to a different country, they may measure length in different units rather than the unit i measure. So will i just give the Numerical value and some dimension unit, which in each country some person will convert my unit afterwards?

Or simply how does it work

Comment: Are you asking about comparisons such as $1\mbox{m}/\mbox{s}=3.6\mbox{km}/\mbox{hr}$?

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions do not depend on what exact measurement quantity you are relating. For example, velocity may be given as meters/second. We are using meters and seconds here just as a matter of convenience, all that matters is that we use some unit of length and divide it by some unit of time. If you were using kilometers/hour instead, you would have to perform the relevant calculation to convert to meters/second if you so desired.

You might be interested in knowing there quantities which are dimensionless, such as Mach speed for example. This arises because these quantities are usually given as ratios of other quantities with the relevant dimensions (m/s in the case of Mach speed)

Comment: I would not say that a Mach number is dimensionless, but rather that one mach (usually written "Mach One" for historical reasons) is a unit of speed equal to the speed of sound. Compare with high-energy physicists, who have an annoying habit of measuring speeds as a fraction of the speed of light, commonly called "setting $c=1$."

Answer (score 0):

Most of the physical properties are related explicitly or implicitly to a dimension space and a dimension time. A mesure of a position or a time is strongly relative to a frame of reference, this is a simple notion of relativity. There are scales $\gamma$ to convert an unit to another similarly to the change of a frame of reference.

By adding the dimension, we can recognize the frame, the physical significance of the property. Normally most of the dimensions expressed as  $L^x.T^x$, with $x,y$ positive integers are invariant by addition (extensive). The acceleration contains $L.T^{-2}$ is intensive, the same for the velocity.

As Antoin Roquentin said dimensionless quantities are interesting but I you rather give the fine structure $\alpha$ constant as an example of an important dimensionless constant. To know more about listen to Paul Dirac himself : [Dimensionless Physical Constants](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-o8mUyq_Wwg)